# Convert multiple lists into dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to convert following

```
Input: Name;class;subject;grade
       sam;4;maths;A
       tom;5;science;B
       kathy;8;biology;A
       nancy;9;maths;B
output: [Name:sam,class:4,subject: maths, grade:A],[name:tom,class:5,subject:science,grade:B],[name: kathy,class:8,subject:biology,grade:B],[name:nancy,class:9,subject:maths,grade:B]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that accepts strings in a way that each piece of data is seperated by a character like : or ;.
Then you can use

```
string.split("the character you used")
```

to get a list of each piece of data stored in a list.

And finally you can store each of these elements in a dictionary and append that dictionary into the list you want to have as your output.

This code I used in my python shell will help you understand these operations better.

```
>>> input_string = "Tom:6:Maths"
>>> list_of_elements = input_string.split(":")
>>> container_dictioanry = {"Name":list_of_elements[0], "class":list_of_elements[1], "grade":list_of_elements[2]}
>>> output_list = []
>>> output_list.append(container_dictioanry)
>>> print(output_list)
[{'Name': 'Tom', 'class': '6', 'grade': 'Maths'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically yours is just a csv text chunk with delimiter `;`

It can be as simple as:

```
input_text = '''<YOUR DATA>'''
lines = input_text.split('\n')
headers = lines[0].split(';')
output = [
    dict(zip(headers, line.split(';')))
    for line in lines[1:]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the text is CSV, you can use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) library.

```
>>> import csv
>>>
>>>
>>> foo = '''Name;class;subject;grade
... sam;4;maths;A
... tom;5;science;B
... kathy;8;biology;A
... nancy;9;maths;B'''
>>>
>>> reader = csv.DictReader(foo.splitlines(), delimiter=';')
>>> print([row for row in reader])
[{'Name': 'sam', 'class': '4', 'subject': 'maths', 'grade': 'A'}, {'Name': 'tom', 'class': '5', 'subject': 'science', 'grade': 'B'}, {'Name': 'kathy', 'class': '8', 'subject': 'biology', 'grade': 'A'}, {'Name': 'nancy', 'class': '9', 'subject': 'maths', 'grade': 'B'}]
```